# React TypeScript: Carousel: rotate an image every 3 seconds

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to rotate the image every 3 seconds but the images seem to load faster and faster the longer it runs for, it's like the set interval is being called many times not just once, do I need `useEffect`?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import image1 from "../images/carousel/screen-1.png";
import image2 from "../images/carousel/screen-2.png";
import image3 from "../images/carousel/screen-3.png";
import image4 from "../images/carousel/screen-4.png";
import image5 from "../images/carousel/screen-5.png";

const Carousel: React.FC = () => {

  interface StateInterface {
    showImage: string;
    startSlide: number;
  }

  const [state, setState] = useState<StateInterface>({
    showImage: image1,
    startSlide: 0
  });

  setInterval(() => {
   console.log('Im Starting'); // <== this prints many times, over and over
    const images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5]
    let currentIndex = state.startSlide;
    if (currentIndex < 5) currentIndex++;
    else currentIndex = 1;
    setState({ ...state, showImage: images[currentIndex], startSlide:currentIndex }); 
  }, 3000);

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      <img src={state.showImage}></img>
    </div>
  );
};

export { Carousel };
```

Should `showImage` be type of `string` or HTMLObject?? or Similar??

Comment: Why don't you declare an array of images instead, then increment the index of the array

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to assign a variable from a string.
it's like trying to do this

```
const x ="Carousel" 
x()
```

just add all the images to an array and instead of itrate their names return the there index inside the array

and add **startSlide** to the state

```
 interface StateInterface {
    showImage: string;
    startSlide:int
  }


  setInterval(() => {
    const images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5]
    let currentIndex = this.state.startSlide
    if (startSlide < 5) currentIndex++;
    else currentIndex = 1;
    setState({ ...state, showImage: images[currentIndex], startSlide:currentIndex }); 
  }, 3000);
```

Comment: This looks like the right direction, but what about the type for `showImage`, should it be `string` or another type?

Comment: no its the image from the import. try it first see if it's working for you

Comment: the second image loads, but after that, it just keeps loading the second image and we never see the 3rd, 4th or 5th and it never goes back to 1. When I console.log(images[startSlide])  I get `/static/media/screen-4.9ccd510c.png` and other random numbers

Comment: No but I think when the state change it triggers a re-render and the `let startSlide = 0;` gets called again??

Comment: the error i get now is `The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.ts(7041)`

Comment: it now shows each of the images, then on the first loop the images load for  1ms and then tries to load again for 1ms, I still think the state change is causing the reset, is useEffect needed?